# Dragging SUMIF formula returns 0 as a result

Tags: excel-formula

I am attempting to extend a workbook to include new columns by dragging the existing formulas with updated cell references.  All of the original formulas work in the new columns except a group of `SUMIF` formulas.

For example, before I made any changes the last column of row 14 was column `BC` with this formula `=SUMIF($A:$A,$B14,BC:BC)`. This formula displays the desired result which is 100.

When I drag this formula to column `BD` it changes to `=SUMIF($A:$A,$B14,BD:BD)`.  This appears to be the same formula structure as column BC yet there is no result displayed; it should also display 100.

I have tried changing the calculation to automatic, CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, changing the cell format.  Nothing has worked so far and I'm at a loss.  Thanks for in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Is there data in col BD? Does the contents of cell B14 match the contents of range BD?

Comment: Could you share a short sample of your data ...

Comment: I figured out the problem.  There were hidden rows that also needed to be dragged over for the formula to work correctly.  I appreciate the quick responses!